# How to solve permission denied error with Python arsenic in a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, firefox

I am trying to run an arsenic script in a Python shell in a Docker container. I am using Firefox as the browser, and am installing it in the Dockerfile:

```
...
# Install specific version of Firefox from source
RUN wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/53.0/linux-$(uname -m)/en-US/firefox-53.0.tar.bz2
RUN tar -xjf firefox-53.0.tar.bz2
RUN mv firefox /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/firefox
RUN chown -hR $USER:$USER /usr/local/bin/firefox

# Install GeckoDriver
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.16.1/geckodriver-v0.16.1-linux64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf geckodriver*
RUN chmod +x geckodriver
RUN mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
...
```

However, when I try using arsenic in the Python shell in the Docker container, I get a permission denied error:

```
/app/scraper/scrape_page_task.py in scraper(url, i, timeout, start, service, browser)
    106 async def scraper(url, i=-1, timeout=60, start=None, service=None, browser=None):
    107 
--> 108     async with get_session(service, browser) as session:
    109         try:
    110             await asyncio.wait_for(session.get(url), timeout=timeout)

/app/scraper/arsenic/__init__.py in __aenter__(self)
     14 
     15     async def __aenter__(self):
---> 16         self.session = await start_session(self.service, self.browser, self.bind)
     17         return self.session
     18 

/app/scraper/arsenic/__init__.py in start_session(service, browser, bind)
     27 async def start_session(service: Service, browser: Browser, bind=""):
     28     driver = await service.start()
---> 29     return await driver.new_session(browser, bind=bind)
     30 
     31 

/app/scraper/arsenic/webdriver.py in new_session(self, browser, bind)
     38 
     39     async def new_session(self, browser: Browser, bind="") -> Session:
---> 40         status, response = await self.connection.request(
     41             url="/session",
     42             method="POST",

/app/scraper/arsenic/connection.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     53     @wraps(func)
     54     async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
---> 55         return await asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(func(*args, **kwargs))
     56 
     57     return wrapper

/app/scraper/arsenic/connection.py in request(self, url, method, data, timeout)
    119                 data=data,
    120             )
--> 121             check_response_error(data=data, status=response.status)
    122             return response.status, data
    123 

/app/scraper/arsenic/connection.py in check_response_error(status, data)
     70 def check_response_error(*, status: int, data: Any) -> None:
     71     if status >= 400:
---> 72         errors.raise_exception(data, status)
     73     if not isinstance(data, dict):
     74         return

/app/scraper/arsenic/errors.py in raise_exception(data, status)
    107             status=status,
    108         )
--> 109     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

UnknownArsenicError: ('Failed to start browser /usr/local/bin/firefox: permission denied', None, 'stack backtrace:\n   0:           0x4fa94d - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h45ace4059cd74233\n   1:           0x4fae32 - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::hb5a725a088a2a2fc\n   2:           0x4349d9 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::h449345a591a119fd\n   3:           0x43eaf8 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::h53f581202e4008b4\n   4:           0x442839 - <geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler as webdriver::server::WebDriverHandler<geckodriver::marionette::GeckoExtensionRoute>>::handle_command::hd89c5efbeb4c7cd5\n   5:           0x434e94 - webdriver::server::start::{{closure}}::h5e71183f67357de6\n   6:           0x408627 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h8c30e6af4c7f85af\n   7:           0x5b77fa - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic\n                        at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-musl-linux/build/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:98\n   8:           0x416e57 - <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box::h3f273b2445d78deb\n   9:           0x5b0014 - alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()>\n                        at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-musl-linux/build/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:624\n                         - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread\n                        at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-musl-linux/build/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21\n                         - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start\n                        at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-musl-linux/build/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84')
```

The permissions on the /usr/local/bin/firefox look like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root  root     4096 Apr 14  2017 firefox
```

It would be great if someone could point out what am I doing wrong with the permissions.

Comment: Are you using the same machine to build the image and to run the docker container? If you are using a laptop and a raspberry, it could be an architecture issue

Comment: Your `/usr/local/bin/firefox` is a directory, not an executable binary.  (And in general I'd expect the tar file you're downloading to contain a complete install tree and not just a single binary.)

Comment: @DavidMaze that might be a good way to do. I'd still expect an error saying that it's a directory, rather than a file, but I'll try with specifying the path to the executable.

Comment: @Clauz architecture issue in which sense?

Comment: In the sense of arm binaries vs x86 binaries (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux-supported_computer_architectures)

Comment: ok, didn't know that these can cause permission issues. thanks for the heads up